# How to make that all posts with a category belong also to another

Tags: categories, mysql

I'd like to make that all my posts in the category A belong also to category B (so after that they would belong both to A and B), is there any plugin or MySQL query that could allow me to do that easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bulk edit posts in the admin.  I have never tried more than 500 or so but you can display 999 per page. To have more than the default 20 click screen options.

Click posts-->filter by Category A
Click  Edit---> select all posts ( clicking top square next to "title")-->Apply
Click Category B and Update.

Comment: I'm doing it right now. No the best solution (I'm displaying 500 posts following this little tip http://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-more-than-15-posts-in-admins-manage-gt-posts, like you), but it works. Slow, but works. I guess a MySQL query should do the same, but much faster.